# What is "Detach from Market"? What does it do?

Tags: titanium-backup

What is "Detach from Market" in Titanium Backup? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Titanium Backup Technical FAQ](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-technical-faq.html#can-tell-market-do-not-want-to-update-specific-app) states: This option tells the Market that you do not want to update a specific app.

[image: "Detach from Market" option screenshot]

This option is especially useful if you need to unlink wrongly linked Android apps from Play Store, as [this article](http://www.guidingtech.com/16288/unlink-wrongly-linked-android-apps-play-store/) explains.

Comment: Does this not work for certain apps?  Mine keeps updating regardless.